# Regular expression to correct email address

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I need help in writing one regular expression where I want to remove unwanted characters in the start and end of the email address. For example:

```
z>user1@hotmail.com<kt
z>user2@hotmail.pk<kt
z>puser3@yahoo.com<kt
z>npuser4@yaoo.uk<kt
```

After applying regular expression my emails should look like:

```
user1@hotmail.com
user2@hotmail.pk
puser3@yahoo.com
npuser4@yaoo.uk
```

Regular expression should not applied if email address is already correct.

Comment: These are good examples of what you want done.  Can you tell us what you have tried as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try deleting matches of

```
^[^>]*>|<[^>]*$
```

([**demo**](http://rubular.com/r/CtBmt032s3))

---

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/84uKiwAAgFJ-SBAV)

Answer (score 0):

Find `^[^>]*>([^<]*)<*.*$` and replace it with `\1`

Here's an [example on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jM9wH9)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a capturing group on anything between the characters you don't want. For example,

```
/>([\w|\d]+@[\w\d]+.\w+)</
```

Basically, any part that the regexp inside () matches is saved in a capturing group. This one matches anything that's inside >here< that starts with a bunch of characters or digits, has an @, has one or more word or digit characters, then a period, then some word characters. Should match any valid email address.

If you need characters besides >< to be matched, make a **character class**. That's what those square bracketed bits are. If you replace > with `[.,></?;:'"]` it'll match any of those characters.

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/cYZAObTKF8) (Look at the match groups)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing the point of a regular expression slightly. A regular expression defines the 'shape' of a string and return whether or not the string conforms to that shape. A simple expression for an email address might be something like:
[a-z][A-Z][0-9]*.?[a-z][A-Z][0-9]+@[a-z][A-Z][0-9]*.[a-z]+

But it is not simple to write one catch-all regular expression for an email address. Really, what you need to do to check it properly is:

1. Ensure there is one and only one '@'-sign.
2. Check that the part before the at sign conforms to a regular expression for this part:

   - Characters
   - Digits
   - Extended characters: .-'_  (that list may not be complete)
3. Check that the part after the @-sign conforms to the reg-ex for domain names:

   - Characters
   - Digits
   - Extended characters: . -
   - Must start with character or digit and must end with a proper domain name ending.